# React-router custom prop not passing to component. ternary operator not working correctly

Tags: reactjs

In React i have my App.js page where i keep my states. I'm importing user1.js component to App.js, and in user1.js component i have a link button that takes me to path /user2.

When i click the button, React will set state property called testValue to true and in user2.js page ternary operator should choose the first value -

test works

because of that. But for some reason it does not work.

Any help?

**APP.JS**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import User1 from './components/user1';


    class App extends Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            testValue:false  
        };

      }

      change = () => {
        this.setState({ 
          testValue:true  
        },() => {
          console.log(this.state.testValue) 

        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <User1 change={this.change}/>
          </div> 


        );
      }

    }

    export default App;
```

**USER1.JS**

```
import React from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import  User2  from './user2.js';

const User1 = (props) => {


    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>

            <Link to ="/user2">
                    <button onClick={props.change}>Next page</button> 
            </Link>


            <Switch>
                    <Route path="/user2" exact component={User2}/>
            </Switch>


        </div>   
      </BrowserRouter>

    ); // end of return
};




export default User1;
```

**USER2.JS**

```
import React from 'react';

const User2 = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    return(
        <div>
            {props.testValue ?
               <p>test works</p>
            :
               <p>test does not work</p>
            }

        </div>

    );

};    

export default User2;
```

**This is what i expected -**

test works

**This is what i got -**

test does not work

Comment: What does the console.log statement in USER2.js show? It looks to me like you're not passing *any* props to User2.

Comment: {history: {…}, location: {…}, match: {…}, staticContext: undefined}
history: {length: 10, action: "PUSH", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
location: {pathname: "/user2", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "lwe9uf"}
match: {path: "/user2", url: "/user2", isExact: true, params: {…}}
staticContext: undefined
__proto__: Object

Comment: What does console.log(props.testValue) show?

Comment: it shows undefined

Comment: So that's why the ternary isn't working! `undefined`, if you test it as a boolean, evaluates to false. You're never actually passing any props to User2 anywhere.

Comment: just use `render` instead of `component`... `<Route path="/user2" exact render={(props) => <User2 {...props} testValue={true} />}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pass a custom property through to a component rendered via a route. [Recommended way to do that](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components/route-rendering-props) is to use the `render` method.

```
<Route path="/user2" exact render={(props) => <User2 {...props} testValue={true} />} />
```

I think a valid inquiry here would be what are you wanting to pass through as an extra prop? whats the use case here? You may be trying to pass data in a way you shouldn't (context would be nice :D).